# How to set bootstrap class `pull-right` when element is loading dynamically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar inside the tab-content that has `pull-right` bootstrap class ,we are rendering element `js-property-panel` based on user selection so when this element loads it is overlapping on navbar. So both are iniside cols 10. How can i set position of navbar using `pull-right` when `js-property-panel` loads it should moved to right ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{'col-md-12':isCollapsed,'col-md-10':!isCollapsed,'tabContentCollapse-padding':isCollapsed}">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right">
            <div class="container-fluid">

              //navbar stuff here 

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="active" id="tab">
            <div>
                <div id="home" class="fade in active">
                    <div class="modeler">
                        <div id="canvas" style="height:80vh;"></div>
                        <div id="js-properties-panel"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Are you looking for a pure css solution? As this can be achieved with
  javascript pretty easily.
- Also here is a link of [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) that    might be useful to
  introduce conditional styling using css.

Update:
Here is how far I could get to- please follow the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/hskjysrr/) here

```html
<div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{'col-md-12':isCollapsed,'col-md-10':!isCollapsed,'tabContentCollapse-padding':isCollapsed}">
  <div class="tab-content row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 navwrapper">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          //navbar stuff here

        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6" id="tab">
      <div>
        <div id="home" class="fade in active">
          <div class="modeler">

            <div id="js-properties-panel" class="panel-contents">
              sample content
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Observations:

- What you are trying to achieve is controlling the style of an element
  higher up the DOM tree using a state an element lower down the tree.
- Neither those elements are direct parent-child nor are those siblings
  so you could control using common class and may be adding a
  :not(:empty) selector.
- You could still use the [column-ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to a certain extend though

Comment: Yes i am looking for Css solution.